# How long does it take for the first round review of physical review letters?

Tags: publications, journals, peer-review, paper-submission, editors

I am wondering how long it takes for the first round review for physical review letters (PRL) on average. I have three referees. One of the referees returned the report in 4 weeks. But the other two referees have not responded to the review requests for 5 weeks. Is it common for PRL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be long; 4 weeks is not uncommon, but much past 6 usually triggers some editorial action.  Fortunately APS has a good manuscript system so it’s easy to see of the editor is trying to move things along: watch for reminders sent to referee(s) in the audit trail.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What kind of editorial action will happen if it passes 6 weeks?

Comment: Beware the second round of reminders to the referees! For my last paper

Comment: ... Sent there, we asked what was going on after 2 or 3 months. The editor gave up waiting and sent the only report he had received...

Comment: @NewKolege normally the system will start sending reminders much more regularly after 4 weeks.  After a few of those reminders (~10-14 days) the editor has the choice of either go forward with the reports already submitted or (if she/he cannot reach a decision) send to another referee.  My experience is that, unless the paper appears marginal to the handling editor, 1 referee report might be enough (especially if the recommendation is to reject).

Comment: @ZeroTheHero That sounds reasonable. I might get the conclusion of reviews in one or two weeks.

Comment: @Adam Was the only report good or bad? If you had the second round of review, did they add any referees since you only had one referee in the first round?

Comment: @NewKolege The report was somewhat ok (not accepted, but a winnable fight). On the second round, the report was positive, but advised for another referee to take a look (I can't remember if the editor sent the paper to the second referee before the first referee's reply, but it is quite probable). We also managed to convince the second referee to accept the paper in the end!